# The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to create my grunt build but stuck in following error

```
npm WARN package.json Dependency 'grunt' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using 'grunt@~0.4.2' from dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-requirejs@0.4.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-config@0.1.8 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-string-replace@0.2.8 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.10.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.11.0 wants grunt@~0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-uglify@0.8.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-exec@0.4.6 wants grunt@~0.4
```

As [here](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/431) mentioned, I uninstalled my node,npm and grunt and reinstalled them but still facing same issue ?

Any idea ?

My JSON dependencies are :

```
"dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-config": "~0.1.4",
    "grunt-string-replace": "~0.2.7",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": ">0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": ">0.3.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": ">=0.3.0",
    "requirejs": ">=2.1.10",
    "grunt-exec": "~0.4.5"
  }
```

Same thing is working fine for my colleague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar error like this today, and fixed it by upgrading npm:

```
npm install -g npm
```

I had version 2.14 and after upgrading it became 3.8

Comment: @osiris355 you're welcome, pls check https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally

Comment: npm WARN install Refusing to install npm as a dependency of itself

Answer (score 2):

You declared grunt dependency twice. One for development and one that is not. You also have a different version rule for both. This is what causes the conflict.

You should remove one of these. (usually grunt is part of devdependencies)

dependencies

```
"grunt": "~0.4.2",
```

devDependencies

```
"grunt": "0.4.2",
```

Edit:

I tested it, this solves the problem:

```
"dependencies": {
  "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
  "grunt-config": "~0.1.4",
  "grunt-string-replace": "~0.2.7",
  "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
  "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.10.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "~0.4.2",
  "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
  "grunt-contrib-jshint": ">0.8.0",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": ">0.3.2",
  "load-grunt-tasks": ">=0.3.0",
  "requirejs": ">=2.1.10",
  "grunt-exec": "~0.4.5"
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but its not working. I am getting same error. Conflict is only warning not error I think, so issue may be something else.

Comment: Did you reinstall the npm modules after it?

Comment: After removing grunt dependencies ?

Comment: Yes I reinstalled npm but still facing same issue :(

Comment: Please, check my edit. I put the whole dependency part. Delete the node_modules directory, then run `npm install`.

Comment: update your npm like the other answer says. worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Updating all my global npm packages fixed the issue for me:

```
npm update -g
```